# Set Ajax ConfirmButtonExtender ConfirmText value dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have this ajax ConfirmButtonExtender in my page with the ConfirmText set to a static value ***Are you sure you want to void this order?.***

```
<ajaxToolKit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbe_btnVoid" runat="server" ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to void this order?" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnTarget" /> '
```

Now, I have created a function that returns a string supposedly in lieu of the static value of the confirmtext as follows:

```
public static string setConfirmTextValue()
{
  return "Note:\n\nThis will void your order.\n\nProceed?";
}
```

Above function works when used in a Button inside a gridview and displays the confirmtext accordingly but when used in a Button on the page, the confirm text is blank.  I am setting the confirmtext value of the Button inside the gridview as follows:

```
ConfirmText='<%# Utils.setConfirmTextValue() %>'
```

I am using the same with the Button outside of the gridview.  Any suggestions/thoughts on this please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to set the ConfirmText for the Extender on a button outside your GridView you could just set it in your page load.

```
if(!isPostBack)
{
   cbe_btnVoid.ConfirmText = Utils.setConfirmTextValue();
}
```

There could well be a way to bind it without using code behind, I don't remember ever seeing <%# ... %> tags outside a control that uses a DataSource.

Comment: I thought I acknowledged this before.  Thank you.

Comment: @jaytapaoan Oh, I'd forgotten about this, glad it helped